# SP.ContentType.get_parent(), how to get name?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, csom

The code below works only to get SharePoint 2013 Foundation list content type and content type url, but I cant get the parent content type.

It returns an object but when I try to access properties `ct.get_parent().get_name()` I get error:

> The property or field 'Name' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

```
var listContentTypes;
    var contentTypeName = "";
    var ctTemplateUrl;

    function runCSOMCall() {

        var targetWeb;
        var list;
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
       // var ctObject = new SP.ContentType();
        targetWeb = ctx.get_web();
        list = targetWeb.get_lists(); 
        targetList = list.getByTitle("Project Documents"); //get the list details
        ctx.load(targetWeb);
        ctx.load(targetList);
        listContentTypes = targetList.get_contentTypes();
        ctx.load(listContentTypes);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){

        var ct_enumerator = listContentTypes.getEnumerator();

        while (ct_enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var ct = ct_enumerator.get_current();
            ctTemplateUrl = ct.get_documentTemplateUrl();
                 //get content type name
                contentTypeName += 'Content types in this list: ' +  ct.get_name() + ' *** Parent: ' + ct.get_parent() + ' ***Template URL' + ctTemplateUrl + '\n';

         var parent=ct.get_parent();                
            ctx.load(parent,'Name', 'Id');//, 'Include(name)');
         }

        console.log(contentTypeName);

        // some other info

         var message = "List info :";
         message += "\n list title: " + targetList.get_title();
              //message += "\n list content types: " + targetList.get_contentTypes();
        $get('outputHtml').innerHTML = message;


        }, function() {
            $get('outputHtml').innerHTML = 'Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace();
        });
    }
    window['runCSOMCall'] = runCSOMCall;

})();



_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runCSOMCall");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute a query again to fetch that, so modify

```
var parent=ct.get_parent();                
ctx.load(parent,'Name', 'Id');//, 'Include(name)');
```

to something like

```
var parent=ct.get_parent();                
ctx.load(parent,'Name', 'Id');

ctx.executeQuery(function(){
     // Here you will have `ct.get_parent().get_name();
}, 
function() {
     $get('outputHtml').innerHTML = 'Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace();
});
```